# What is the best way to implement global variables to whole code in java

Tags: java-8

I need to create several variables in Java. My requirements as follows.

> 1. Variables should be initialized at the initialization of the project in the beginning. But, variable should have a default value (in case, if a variable is not initialized that should contain the default value).
> 2. Variables need to be accessed through out the code.

I need a proper way in Java 8.

Comment: How should this variable be initialized?

Comment: This generally violates encapsulation given that there is global state somewhere.  Why do you feel the need for these global variables?

Comment: @Mureinik this fields will be initialized by a message received from another process.

Comment: @Makoto Yes of course. But the requirement is  after initializing them I need to access them from anywhere of the code. This will reduce huge amount of arguments that need to pass into a method.

Comment: Are you using a framework with dependency injection, like Spring or Guice, which could make that a lot cleaner?

Comment: Of course not. I am not using any framework for this purpose. I need a simple way to do this.

Comment: “per-processor macros”? Do you mean “pre-processor macros”? Still, I don’t see how they solve that problem. C++ has global variables, which intrinsically solves the problem, however, there’s no connection to the pre-processor.

Comment: Yes should be pre - processor. corrected it. Watch this http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/

Comment: If you're really using C++ preprocessor macros to do this in C++, either you're using them incorrectly or don't understand what you're actually doing. The preprocessor macros just literally replace any instance of you calling the macro with the defined code. They cannot be changed programmatically, as when the code compiles they're effectively not there.

Comment: Of course yes. I might get confused when posting the question.  thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you create a Resources class with `public static` members, you can access them by referencing them like, for example, `Resources.myGlobalData`, anywhere you import that class.

So, (untested but should be accurate)

```
public class Resources {
    public static int count = 1; // default initialization to 1
}
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Resources.count++;
        System.out.println(Resources.count); // prints 2
    }
}
```

However, I would urge you to reconsider your design, as anytime you have mutable global state, you're asking for bugs when the global state is (or isn't) changed.

If you actually want to generate compile-time constants like C-style `#DEFINE` preprocessor macros, you can use `public static final` fields. These do not carry the problems of global state because the `final` keyword makes them immutable. (Most compilers will inline the value at compile-time, just like a `#DEFINE` is implemented in C-style languages.)

Comment: If I prefer this solution will I be able to assign values to `public static` methods at run time(in the beginning of process). What do you mean by mutable global state? Can you please give me an example where I'm in trouble if I use this?

Comment: Mutable: liable to change. For a bit of elaboration on why mutable globals are bad, see http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil.

Comment: Thank you. I will go through this.

Comment: This is a good source with detail description. Thank you for sharing this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the variable should have a primitive type? And actually vary (ie, you're not looking for a constant)? If you're using Spring you'd make the variable a member variable of a bean class, then autowire that bean into any of the classes you'd want to access it from.

Comment: Yes of course. Variables have primitive types. Most of the time those are Strings and int.  I am not clear about`Spring`. Are you talking about Java Spring framework?

Comment: Check out the guides at spring.io.